# Custom owl carousel pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

```
<div class="link">
    <div><a href="#">Mobile App</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Web App</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Desktop App</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Cloud App</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Machine App</a></div>
</div>
<div class="my-carousel owl-carousel">
    <div><img src="asset/img/mobileapp.png" title="Mobile App" /></div>
    <div><img src="asset/img/webapp.png" title="Web App" /></div>
    <div><img src="asset/img/desktopapp.png" title="Desktop App" /></div>
    <div><img src="asset/img/cloudapp.png" title="Cloud App" /></div>
    <div><img src="asset/img/machineapp.png" title="Machine App" /></div>
</div>
```

I want to create a custom pagination in owl carousel. i want a situation where whenever i click on say "mobile app", it should take me to the corresponding view. and when ever the carousel changes, the link should be updated with jquery. The link is on the left of my view, while the slider is on the right. so whenever the carousel changes, the link should be updated. i don't know how to achieve this with jquery. Please can someone help out!

Comment: can you show a working fiddle

Comment: @Rani Moreles Rubillos, You can check out this website. https://www.matrixlms.com/info/features

Comment: ok that is fine so I could see and know what you mean

Comment: https://www.matrixlms.com/info/features. this is it. thank you.